# $T(Y)\subset Y$ for $Y:=\bigcap_{n\geq 1}T^n(X)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $T\colon X\to X$ and $Y:=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}T^nX$.

Do we have $T\colon Y\to Y$?
I think no

$$
T(Y)\subset\bigcap_{n=2}^{\infty}T^nX\not\subset \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}T^nX=Y.
$$

Conversely, we have $Y\subset \bigcap_{n\geq 2}T^nX$.

A bit confused since it is said that there is some function from Y to Y and this function is even called T.

Comment: Use that $T X\subseteq X$ and apply $T$ on both sides.

Comment: Oh you are right... so indeed $T(Y)\subset Y$ hence $T_{|Y}\colon Y\to Y$ is allright.

Answer (score 1):

It is not so trivial after all. In general you need not have $TY=Y$. ($TY\subset Y$ is trivially true).

Example: We will define $X$ as a subset of ${\Bbb N}_0^2$ and a dynamical system on it.

Set $\Omega_0=\{(0,0),(0,1),...\}$ and
for $n\geq 1 : \Omega_n = \{ (n,1),...,(n,n)\}$.
We let $X=\bigcup_{n\geq 0} \Omega_n$. The dynamics is as follows:

$T(0,k)=(0,k+1)$ (a right shift) and for $2\leq k\leq n : T(n,k)=(n,k-1)$ (a left shift at level $n$). Finally $T(n,1)=(0,0)$, $n\geq 1$.

Then $Y=\bigcap T^n X=\Omega_0$ but $TY$ does not contain the point $(0,0)\in Y$.

Perhaps an intuitive explanantion of what is going on may help: $T$ defines a right shift on $\Omega_0$.  Now, for every $n\geq 1$ the chain $\Omega_n$ is nilpotent (becomes empty after $n+1$ iterations), so will not belong to $Y$. On the other hand $(0,0)$ is in the image of $T^n X$ for every $n\geq 1$, so $Y=\Omega_0$. But $(0,0)$ has no preimage in $Y$.

Comment: My question only was if it is correct  to say $T\colon Y\to Y$ and I guess thats okay since $T(Y)\subset Y$. Or I guess what was really meant is if we restrict $T$ to $Y$ then $T_{|Y}\colon Y\to Y$ (since originally, T is defined on X).

Comment: Ok, but in the beginning there was a question also about $TY=Y$ which I found intriguing.

Comment: You are right. And thank you very much for your great example.